# is the gcc link the all file in /lib /lib64 /usr/lib/ /usr/llib64?

Tags: gcc

I found there are path /lib /lib64 /usr/lib/ /usr/llib64 in my linux server?

how the gcc found the paths? if found all path？　if it has sequence or priority?

Comment: it's linker that searches libraries. You can run "ld  --verbose" to check the SEARCH_DIR

Comment: ld --verbose seem not work, but ldconfig --verbose